# Is there a way to change the voice of the workout guide in Samsung Health?

Tags: languages

It was a British lady with a lovely voice, and now it’s a US-American lady with a voice that frankly doesn’t appeal to me. I don’t see a way to change it, though. The phone’s language is set to British English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the voice package to the app and choose it.  For example, if I Google search "Samsung TTS" I get a result for [Samsung TTS Australian English Default voice 1](https://galaxystore.samsung.com/detail/com.samsung.SMT.lang_en_au_f00?langCd=en) that I can install via the galaxy store. It's then just a matter of going to Settings, Controls, Language and input, Text-to-Speech options... then choose the voice you want.

Your probably after the [Samsung TTS UK English Default voice 1](https://galaxystore.samsung.com/detail/com.samsung.SMT.lang_en_gb_f00?langCd=en)

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I'm surprised the new phone came with fewer voice packages than the previous one; no packages were ever downloaded on the previous one!